# Check sentences if have same words

Tags: php, mysql, sql

`tb_content`(left) and `tb_word`(right) :

```
=====================================    ================================
|id|sentence |sentence_id|content_id|    |id|word|sentence_id|content_id|
=====================================    ================================
| 1|sentence1|    0      |    1     |    | 1|  a |     0     |    1     |
| 2|sentence2|    1      |    1     |    | 2|  b |     0     |    1     |
| 3|sentence5|    0      |    2     |    | 3|  c |     1     |    1     |
| 4|sentence6|    1      |    2     |    | 4|  a |     1     |    1     |
| 5|sentence7|    2      |    2     |    | 5|  e |     1     |    1     |
=====================================    | 6|  f |     0     |    2     |
                                         | 7|  g |     1     |    2     |
                                         | 8|  h |     1     |    2     |
                                         | 9|  i |     1     |    2     |
                                         |10|  f |     2     |    2     |
                                         |11|  h |     2     |    2     |
                                         |12|  f |     2     |    2     |
                                         ================================
```

I need to check if every sentence consist of words that owned by other sentences in every `content_id`.

for example :

Check for the `content_id` = `1` they are `sentence1` and `sentence2`. from `tb_word`, we can see that `sentence1` and `sentence2` consist of the same word `a`. if the number of `a` in two sentences is `>=2`, then `a` will be the result. So if I print the result, it must be :
`00Array ( [0] => a [1] => b) 01Array ( [3] => a ) 10Array ( [3] => a )11Array ( [0] => c [1] => a [2] => e)` where `00` means `sentence_id` = `0` and `sentence_id` = `0`

first, I make `functionTotal` to count how many `sentence` that owned by every  `content_id` :

```
$total = array();
$sql = mysql_query('select content_id, count(*) as RowAmount 
       from tb_content Group By contente_id') or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $total[] = $row['RowAmount']; 
}
return $total;
```

From that function I get the value of `$total` and from that I need to check the similarity of some words (from `tb_word`) between all the possibilities of 2 `sentence`

```
foreach ($total as $content_id => $totals){
for ($x=0; $x <= ($totals-1); $x++) {
    for ($y=0; $y <= ($totals-1); $y++) {
      $shared = getShared($x, $y);
    }
}
```

the function of `getShared` is :

```
function getShared ($x, $y){
    $token = array();
    $shared = array();
    $i = 0;
    if ($x == $y) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT word FROM `tb_word`
                             WHERE sentence_id ='$x' ");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $shared[$i] = $row['word'];
            $i++;
        }

    } else {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT word, count(word) as jml 
                             FROM `tb_word` WHERE sentence_id ='$x' 
                             OR sentence_id ='$y' 
                             GROUP BY word ");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $jml = $row['jml'];
            $token[$i] = $row['word'];
            if ($jml >= 2) {
                $shared[$i] = $token[$i];
            }
            $i++;
        }
```

But the result I get is still wrong. the result still mix between different `content_id`. the result must be group by `content_id` also. sorry for my bad english and my bad explanation. cmiiw, please help me.. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one can be actually done by DBMS itself, two steps in one query. First, you make a self join in order to prepare sentence combinations within the same content:

```
SELECT a.content_id,
       a.sentence_id AS sentence_id_1,
       b.sentence_id AS sentence_id_2
FROM   tb_content AS a
       JOIN tb_content AS b
         ON ( a.content_id = b.content_id
              AND a.sentence_id <= b.sentence_id )
```

The "<=" will keep same sentence joins, like "1-1" or "2-2", and yet avoid bidirectional repetitions, like "1-2" and "2-1". Next you can join the above result with words and count the number of occurances. Like that:

```
SELECT s.content_id,
       s.sentence_id_1,
       s.sentence_id_2,
       c.word,
       Count(*) AS jml
FROM   (SELECT a.content_id,
               a.sentence_id AS sentence_id_1,
               b.sentence_id AS sentence_id_2
        FROM   tb_content AS a
               JOIN tb_content AS b
                 ON ( a.content_id = b.content_id
                      AND a.sentence_id <= b.sentence_id )) AS s
       JOIN tb_word AS c
         ON ( s.content_id = c.content_id
              AND ( c.sentence_id = s.sentence_id_1
                     OR c.sentence_id = s.sentence_id_2 ) )
GROUP  BY s.content_id,
          s.sentence_id_1,
          s.sentence_id_2,
          c.word
HAVING Count(*) >= 2;
```

The result of the above query will give you the container, sentences 1 and 2, the word, and the number of occurances (which is 2 or more). All you need now is collecting the result into the array which as I see you already know to do.

Let me know, if I missunderstood your goal.

Comment: I'll try to explain by example.`Sentence1`=`I read A Good Mind`.`Sentence2`=`A Good Mind is a book written by A`. Then I parse the sentences to get important words only (save in tb_word). The possibilities to check out between 2 sentences are sentence1 and sentence1(1-1),1-2,1-3,2-1,2-2,2-3. for the same number(1-1,2-2) the result are all the words in those sentence, so 1-1 will give me results `good,read,mind`. for the different number (1-2,1-3,etc) check out if there are words in the 1st sentence which are also owned by the 2nd sentence. so for 1-2, it will give me result `good` and `mind`.

Comment: I've tried your code. But when the 2nd sentence consist of 2 same words or more although the 1st sentence doesnt consist of that words, they still be included in the result.

Comment: and also my main issue is not only work in one document, but in many documents ( i declare it as `content_id`). my example above is the explanation process in one document that consist of 2 sentences.

Comment: Ok, I didn't take into consideration repetitions. You can avoid it either by changing `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT c.sentence_id)`, or by already selecting distinct values from TB_WORD, like `JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tb_word) AS c`

Comment: As for the issue of working with many documents I don't exactly understand what do you mean by that...

Comment: oh, it works well. thank you so much. document is represented by `content_id` in `tb_content`. But my example in comment above didn't show about that issue.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply `SELECT content_id, word, COUNT(*) as num_appearing FROM tb_word GROUP BY content_id, word`?

**EDIT**: I see the complexity now: your main issue is that the `getShared()` function has two sentence IDs passed to it, but no `content_id` to know which content is being analyzed. You're also assuming that `content_id` and `sentence_id` numbers are consecutive and start at zero. My code doesn't assume that, and pulls those IDs directly from the database.

```
<?php
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_content");
$content = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    if (!isset($content[$row['content_id']])) $content[$row['content_id']] = array();
    $content[$row['content_id']][] = $row['sentence_id'];
}
foreach($content as $content_id => $sentences) {
  foreach($sentences as $sentence_id) {
    foreach($sentences as $compare) {
      $shared = getShared($content_id, $sentence_id, $compare);
    }
  }
}
function getShared($cid, $s1, $s2) {
  $rs = mysql_query("SELECT `word`, COUNT(*) AS 'num' FROM `tb_word` WHERE `content_id`={$cid} AND `sentence_id` IN ({$s1}, {$s2}) GROUP BY `word`");
  $out = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    if ($rs['num'] >= 2) $out[$rs['word']] = $rs['num'];
  }
  return $out;
}
```

Comment: thanks.. I've learned and tried your code, but it (`$out`) gives me blank result.. The result I need is like -> `00Array ( [0] => a [1] => b) 01Array ( [3] => a ) 10Array ( [3] => a )11Array ( [0] => c [1] => a [2] => e)` etc where 00 means sentence_id = 0 and sentence_id = 0, etc..